How to make one function return different types?
I've been thinking about this issue for a very long time; is it possible to write a single function that returns different types for the same operation?
In this case, I have two classes Employee and Payroll that store data in JSON files. I want the classes to be stored in the same class JsonMethods, so an approach like the one described here (using generics and inheriting from a base class) won't apply.
public async Task<List<Employee>> ReadAllEmployees()
{
   string returnText = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(_filePath + "Employees.json");

   if ( returnText is not "" )
   {
      List<Employee>? aJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(returnText);
      if ( aJson != null )
         return aJson;
   }

   return [null];
}

public async Task<List<Payroll>> ReadAllPayrolls()
{
   string returnText = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(_filePath + "Payrolls.json");

   if ( returnText is not "" )
   {
      List<Payroll>? asJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Payroll>>(returnText);
      if ( asJson != null )
         return asJson;
   }

   return [null];
}

I tried replacing the classes with object after letting the classes inherit from Object, which doesn't seem legal (and didn't work anyway)
Is there any way to make this work, or do I just have to stick with two identical functions?

"I want the classes to be stored in the same class" - can you expand on what you mean by this, and why you think that precludes the use of generics?

It's very unclear to me why you think using generics won't work. If you were to change your first method to ReadAllValues<T> and replace every occurrence of "Employee" with "T" in the method body (probably accepting the filename as a parameter) then your code should work...

Whats the issue with Task<List<T>> ReadAllValues<T>(string file);?

I didn't realise it was that simple, thanks Jon! I haven't used generics that much, so I'll start learning about those.

after letting the classes inherit from Object - all classes already implicitly inherit from Object, so no need to do that explicitly

Your return [null] also looks wrong, you should either return null or, better, return new List<T>() or return []

Here's an example of a generic method which can replace your two similar methods:
public async Task<List<T>> ReadAllItems<T>(string fileName)
{
   string returnText = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(_filePath + fileName);

   if ( returnText is { Length: > 0 } )
   {
      List<T>? aJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(returnText);
      if ( aJson != null )
         return aJson;
   }

   return [];
}


Your going to need to add a where T : class constraint to allow null to be added to the list.

If you can't add where T : class, you can still return [default(T)],

I also would use if ( returnText is { Length: > 0 }). This pattern matching expression is equivalent to !String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnText). Otherwise it might not work as expected if the value is null.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes very good point.  A question could be asked "Can File.ReadAllTextAsync return null" but using string.IsNullOrEmpty or is {Length: > 0} (or even !string.IsNullOrWhitespace) is always a good idea!

return [null] is also very bad, it returns a List with one null item

I would return an object and cast the type using an if statement.
